# Regular expression for hexadecimal string

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regex that detect if a string of hexadecimal is only a combination of 00 , 06, 03 and space.

The closest i've found so far is ^(00|06|03)$ but it's still giving me false for 0300

```
0300 will match
0600 0300 match
0612 0300 no match
3030 no match
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close, but you need closure and some safe-guarding:

```js
let v = /^((00|06|03){2}\s)*(00|06|03){2}$/;

[
  '0300',
  '0600 0300',
  '0612 0300',
  '3030',
  '0303 0000',
  '0630 0300',
  '8790 0060',
  '03 0000',
  '0003 0006 0000 0000 0303 0606 0600 0306 0000',
  '0606 0603 0303'
].map(s => console.log("%s : %s", s, v.test(s)));
```

Comment: I've added the space to your solution and it's now perfect. Thanks!

Comment: ^(00|06|03| )*$ this looks to be working as expected

Answer (score 1):

`^(00|06|03)$` will only match '00' or '06' or '03'. If you're expecting this combination to repeat, you need to add +.

Try `^(00|06|03| )+$`

I've included the space in there as well. This will match your scenarios.